# Disable all inputs, set focus on the next once they are enabled again

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get the current/next item in my controller. What I want to do to get the next element and be able to set focus on it. I can do this with javascript, but not sure how to do get the `event` within angular, so I can access the `e.relatedTarget`. I'm also open for improvements and suggestions

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/907gMAFyDiL0QpxX8aAs?p=preview)

```
<input type="text" class="input__text" name="name" ng-model="name" ng-change="bluryLines(name)" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur'}" ng-disabled="blured">

            function focusNextInput (e) {
                console.log('focusNextInput');

                var target = e.target;
                var relatedTarget = e.relatedTarget;

                if (relatedTarget !== null) {
                    console.log('has a related target');
                    relatedTarget.focus();
                }
            }

            $scope.bluryLines = function(value) {
                $scope.blured = true;

                if (value === '') {
                    console.log('value is empty');
                } else {
                    console.log(value);
                }

                $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.blured = false;

                    //how do I get the event here to be passed into the function
                    focusNextInput();
                }, 1000);
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with $event in angular.

```
<input type="text" class="input__text" name="name" ng-model="name" ng-click='functionname($event)'>
```

Regards,
Selvam.M

Comment: `ng-change` does not support `$event`